# Generate Makefile using meson build file

Tags: makefile, gstreamer, gnu-make, autotools, meson-build

In one of our projects we have used Gstreamer good plugins. I see that each element has a Makefile for building.

Now I wanted to upgrade rtpmanager code (https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/master/gst/rtpmanager) inside Gstreamer. But, I see that there are **no Makfiles anymore but 'meson.build' file**.

Currently our project build does not support meson. So, is there a way to **convert the latest rtpmanager code involving meson.build to traditional Makefile kind of build** so that I can integrate its latest changes into my project.

Answer (score 3):

Meson does not and never will generate makefiles.

Comment: So, the only solution is to get the meson build system into the project ?

Comment: It should generate CMakeLists.txt instead.  
Meson is IMHO terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Qemu meson PoC is using a tool to convert ninja files to Makefile:
https://github.com/bonzini/qemu/blob/meson-poc/scripts/ninjatool.py

Comment: Hi elmarco, thankyou for your answer. I tried running ninjatool.py script. It says, it is used to convert build.ninja to Makefile. I do not see any build.ninja file in the gstreamer project, there is only meson.build file. Could you guide me how to proceed ?

Comment: You need to run meson first to configure the project. `meson build` from the source directory. Then you should have a `build/build.ninja` file you can convert.